# Double integral of $\dfrac{y}{x^2y^2+1}dx~dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve the double integral $\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^1\dfrac{y}{x^2y^2+1}dx~dy$ . I'm guessing something with natural log will have to be done. Doing the steps of this problem are more important than the value itself.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't substitute. Just integrate wrt $x$ first.

$$\newcommand{\d}[1][x]{\,\mathbb{d}#1} \int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac{y}{x^2y^2 + 1}\d[x] \d[y] = \int_0^1 \arctan{y} \d[y]$$

And this integral can be easily evaluated by parts ($\d[u] = 1$, $v = \arctan y$).

Answer (score 2):

Make the substitution $\\u = x^{2}y^{2}+1,
\\ du=(2x^{2}y)dy$

The rest is easy stuff.